# low frequency permittivity of metals from Drude's model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

In reference to the [Optical constants of noble metals: the Drude model for microwave modelling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47017/optical-constants-of-noble-metals-the-drude-model-for-microwave-modelling/89021#89021) regarding Drude's model these parameters were listed

$$ \omega_P=1.36\times 10^{16} \text{ rad/s} $$
$$ \gamma=1.05\times 10^{14} \text{ rad/s} $$

If I substitute these values into Drude's formula $$ ϵ(ω)=1−ω_p ^2 /(ω(ω+i/τ)) $$

then near dc $\omega$~0 the real part of $ \epsilon\ $ will be very negative
$ Re(\epsilon(\omega ))$ ~ $-10^4$.

What might this mean physically, how one would interpret the negative energy $W = (1/2) \epsilon\ E^2 $ of a piece of metal placed in electrostatic field?
Or the answer is just that Drude's model breaks down at very low frequencies; if so, why, where and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression for $\epsilon$ above written as real + imaginary part is

$$
\epsilon(\omega) = 1- \frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2 + \Gamma^2}+\frac{i\omega_p^2\Gamma}{\omega^3 + \omega\Gamma^2},
$$

so in fact it is the imaginary part that goes to infinity as $\omega$ is lowered down to 0. What does this mean?

$\epsilon(\omega)$ for metals is defined by the equation

$$
\tilde{\mathbf P}(\omega) = \epsilon_0(\epsilon(\omega) -1) \tilde{\mathbf E}(\omega),
$$
where $ \tilde{\mathbf P}$ is polarization potential, a quantity defined by the conditions
$$
\partial_t \tilde{\mathbf P} = \tilde{\mathbf j},
$$
$$
\overline{\tilde{\mathbf P}} = 0.
$$
This linear relation between the polarization potential and the electric field phasors is approximately valid for real metals (Ohm's law).

The greater is the imaginary component of $\epsilon$, the greater is also the component of the phasor $ \tilde{\mathbf P}$ perpendicular to $\tilde{\mathbf E}$. So for low frequency harmonic oscillations, $\tilde{\mathbf P}$ gets very long and has a phase lag behind electric field 90°.

This is understandable, because in the model, the electrons do not experience any restoring force due to metal, so if electric field changes very slowly, the electrons can get very far from their starting position and the amplitude of oscillations can be very high. When the electric field is held constant, there is no oscillation at all and the electrons move with constant velocity, which $\tilde{\mathbf P}$ cannot describe very well, but $\tilde{\mathbf j}$ can. To describe the metal, it is better to use conductivity $\sigma$ defined by
$$
\tilde{\mathbf j}(\omega) = \sigma (\omega) \tilde{\mathbf E}(\omega).
$$

The expression for electric energy density $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon \mathbf E^2$ was derived for idealized situations where we are interested in the field energy outside ideal metals with zero resistance. This is useful in situations when the fields change quasistatically and generation of heat in metals can be neglected.

Drude model describes metal in a better way than that, it allows for non-zero electric field in the metal and for phase lag of current behind this electric field, but this necessarily makes the old expression for electric energy density invalid.

To define the energy for this case, we can begin with the assertion that
$$
\mathbf j\cdot \mathbf E
$$
is the work done by the electric field on the charge carriers per unit time per unit volume of metal, and repeat the derivation from electrostatics. When this is done, we end up with Poynting theorem which connects $\mathbf j$ and fields $\mathbf E, \mathbf B$ in a way that motivates definition of EM energy density

$$
u = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2,
$$
which does not contain any material properties of the matter.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not understand. Let us just talk about dc, what is the static permittivity of metals? Is it really negative, and if so, what electrostatic measurement would verify it? If I have a bunch of nails all parallel and embedded in styro-foam would I really measure negative capacitance when I place the matrix between two metal plates? In what sense will I see the manifestation of the negative real part?

Comment: Metals do not have static permittivity in the same sense dielectrics do. If the field oscillates, electric permittivity can be introduced as complex number formally via the second equation above. But for static electric field this loses sense, because the current density $\mathbf j$ is constant in time and there is no definite polarization potential $\mathbf P$ that could be used in the second equation above. In such situations it is better to use conductivity $\sigma$, which makes much more sense and is finite.

Comment: Your example with nails seems too complicated. If you replace the nails by thick metal block, it will increase the capacitance of the capacitor, because inside the block the electric field will have to be zero, which means the potential difference will be present over the two air gaps between the plates and  the block. The capacitance will increase strongly with decreasing the width of the air gaps and will be rather independent of the kind of metal (for quasi-static currents).

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you well you are saying that in a time varying field the apparent permittivity is complex with negative real part but that is really due to the finiteness of conductivity. But then how do you explain that one can make artificial dielectrics and lenses at RF (microwaves) using metal pieces like nails or spheres, etc. that behave as if they had positive permittivity? I have mentioned nails because they are used to make microwave lenses. Anyhow why can't we associate the increase of capacitance you mentioned for a simple metal block as result of positive permittivity?

Comment: The above permittivity and the Drude model is meant to describe what is going on inside metal; boundaries of this metal with dielectric are neglected. The artificial dielectric containing isolated metal pieces may also be ascribed permittivity $\epsilon'$, but this is different from the permittivity $\epsilon$ of the metal. It may very well be that $\epsilon$ has negative real part, while $\epsilon'$ is large and positive. In fact, the denser the metal pieces are, the higher $\epsilon'$ we can expect. This happens because the boundaries metal-dielectric and the gaps will play important role.

Comment: Now we are talking about the same issue, and I am very grateful for your patience but I still have one more question left to clarify this: how can one actually demonstrate that negative real part of metal permittivity at dc by pure electro-static measurement? Also, beside how to measure it what meaning one should/might assign to the imaginary part in an electro-statics experiment?

Comment: No problem, you had good questions and this is an interesting topic. I do now know if there is any way to demonstrate value of permittivity of metal with dc current, but it seems unlikely. The permittivity $\epsilon(\omega)$ is meant as a factor describing response to $oscillating$ fields during stationary  oscillations. Due to the relation $\tilde{j}(t) = -i\omega\epsilon_0(\epsilon(\omega) -1)\tilde{E}(t)$, as $\omega$ approaches 0, the real part of $\epsilon$, has smaller and smaller effect on $\tilde{j}(t)$. The imag. part has substantial effect in this limit, and determines conductivity.